# Unable to import large size of data to database phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm  unable to import large size of data to database phpmyadmin

m edited php.ini file for importing large amount of file. But a message showing after some time

```
Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.
```

please help me

Comment: is this localhost, or hosted?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.

*Belive it or not, phpmyadmin can handle this.*

Comment: Try it again, delete table first. But don't go to another phpmyadmin page while uploading...

Comment: no way friend i am did that lot of time .. what any other solution?

Comment: set max_execution_time to something very high, and try it again.

Comment: An other solution is, to split the file manually and upload the parts.

Comment: Which is what BigDump does automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using phpmyadmin use command line tool

open terminal and write

```
mysql -h host -u username -p
```

provide password

```
source /path/to/file
```

and no time out problem now

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, it did the job for me in the past.
http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php

Answer (score 0):

If your data comes from another database, you can use the database synchronization tool / tab that is available in newer versions of phpmyadmin.

That way you won't have to export and then import and you won´t run into the limit file-size limit for phpmyadmin imports.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file: config.inc.php inside phpmyadmin and add the following line (or edit if it exists):

> $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;

This timeout value is used at the time of import for phpmyadmin which is defined at libraries/config.default.php which is recommended to not to edit. This should solve the script timeout error.